# Mongoose: Query for starts with

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to basically do a username search.

```
User.find({ username: "Mich"})
```

I'd like a query like the above that'll return all users who's username starts with "Mich". Michael, Michaela, MichJagger, etc.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can [search with regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/), this should work in Node

```
User.find({ username: /^Mich/})
```

Note that Mongo supports regex objects, which means you can do

```
var regexp = new RegExp("^"+ req.params.username);
User.find({ username: regexp});
```

or Mongos own regex constructor

```
User.find({ username: {$regex : "^" + req.params.username}});
```

Comment: How would I insert that value? Ie. If I have it req.params.username? That is to say, how would I replace Mich with a variable?

Comment: with template string if anyone interested: ```{ $regex: `^${req.params.username}` }```   ```var regexp = new RegExp(`^${req.params.username}`);```